# How to choose the relaxation time in the Lattice Boltzmann Method?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stability, lattice-boltzmann-methods

We know that the relaxation time is very important in LBM. I have searched lost of papers, but can't find some systematic introductions about the choice of relaxation time in SRT LBM. Could you give some ways or papers to get a suitable relaxation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimensionless relaxation time $\bar{\tau}$ should be chosen as to obtain the correct fluid viscosity. That is :
$$\bar{\tau} = \frac{\mu}{\rho c^2 \Delta t} + \frac{1}{2}$$

where $c$ is the lattice celerity, $\Delta t$ the time step and $\rho$ the density. Generally $\rho$ is chosen as unity in LBM
Therefore, generally, you know the physical property you want to simulate ($\mu$ and $\rho$) and you use a value of $\tau$ that you choose. Then, with this choice of value of $\tau$ (which is generally 1 or lower), you obtain the value of the time step $\Delta t$.

You can find some explanation on this issue in this paper :
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999115001916

However, many books also treat the subject, like this one :
http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8806

Comment: In fact, I don't know the physical property. Because I simulated the case from paper, there is always no physcial property in the paper. So I have doubt about the relaxation time.

Comment: Well what is the Reynolds number? If you know which Reynolds number you want to obtain, since $Re=\frac{\rho u L}{\mu}$, if you know the length of the geometry, the approximative speed, then you can fix $\rho$ and then choose $\mu$ to obtain the right Reynolds number. You must at least have some information about the flow (such as a dimensionless number), otherwise your reference paper does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Another question, if the paper was computated by the FVM, but I use the LBM. So how can I find the relaxation time?

Comment: You can either chose the time step, this will decide the relaxation time, or you can chose the relaxation time (usually ]0.5, 1]), then this will impose the time step. You just need to chose the combination of all parameters in order to reproduce the correct Reynolds number of your simulation. I believe you should take some time to review the bases of LBM, since this is really fundamental to the method.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why the time step effects. Because in the code, the time step is only related to the relaxation. Such as, in my code, dt=dx=1,and I iterate 200,000 times. So where is time steps?

Comment: Because of the above formula. The time step is in the formula which related the dimensionless relaxation time to the physical property. If your time step is fixed to 1  and your lattice spacing is fixed to 1, then you need to fix $\tau$ to recover the right viscosity, that's all.. $\bar{\tau} = \frac{\mu}{\rho c^2 \Delta t} + \frac{1}{2}$ really says it all..

Comment: Yes, this formula is very important. Whether I could think like this, if dx=dt=1 in my code, I don't have to care about the time step, only choose the suitable relaxation time(or the viscosity)? Then you said that  fix relaxation time to recover the right viscosity, is the relaxation time a spelling mistake?

Comment: No it is not a spelling mistake. If $\rho$ $\delta t$ and $\delta x$ are fixed, then you just need to fix $\bar{\tau}$ in order to recover the right viscosity

Comment: Yes, there are two symbol about the viscosity. You wrote it without a line first time,but with a line second time.